# How can a running web deployment process be cancelled?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment

I'm attempting to deploy my web app to a local test server using VS2010 One Click Publish and it seems I've put incorrect settings in to the web deployment dialogue. I didn't realise this until I'd pressed the publish button.

After thinking the deployment was taking an unusually long time, I looked at the Output window and say the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3847,5): Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.  
Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 1 of 10.
```

Now I think I know what I've done wrong, this question isn't about that.

Each attempt is taking about three or four minutes. How can I stop the web deployment process when it is doing something like this?

Comment: @GrantThomas I did think of that, but it seems a bit brutal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press CTRL-BREAK during publishing to cancel the process.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't try that combination. I'll give it a go next time I have the opportunity and mark this answer as such if it works. Thanks very much.